# Deploy a web Application on IIS5.1

Tags: iis

I have created a web application in .net4.0 and want to deploy it as a website rather than virtual directory.

Can Any body help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not in IIS 5.1. You have to upgrade your IIS first otherwise you can make only virtual directory.